# Background rectangle fit to label text in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to get a background around a label that fits the number of lines in the texted in it.  For example, a label with text 'Line1\nLine1\nLine3' would have a larger Y dimension that just 'line1'

What currently happens is all of the labels are the same size and clip-off text that doesn't fit within them, the labels are also inside a recycleview layout because I would like to be able to scroll and update large amount of the labels often.

I have tried a few things but have had no luck, and am struggling to get a variable to be understood where I have added # HERE in the .kv file

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty, Clock, ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TopPostsTest(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        message_height = NumericProperty(20)
        items = ["hello\ntest\ntest", "test, gghgjhgjhgjhgjhghjghjgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhgjhg", "cheese"]
        self.data = [{'text':str(p)} for p in items]

class LabelColor(Label):
    pass

class TruthApp(App):
#    def build(self):
#        return super().build()
    pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TruthApp().run()
```

```
<MainControl@PageLayout>:
    border: "25dp"
    swipe_threshold: 0.4
    TopPostsTest:
    Settings:

<LabelColor>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    text_size: self.size
    halign: 'left'
    valign: 'top'
    font_name: "Assets/Fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf"
    font_size: "12dp"
    multiline: True

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [5, 5, 5, 5]
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba:0,0.9,0.9,1
        Line:
            width:0.8
            rounded_rectangle:(self.x,self.y,self.width,root.height, 5) # HERE

<TopPostsTest>:
    viewclass: 'LabelColor'
    scroll_y: 1
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        id: message_view
        default_size: None, dp(40) # NewHERE
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        padding: ["10dp", "16dp"]
        spacing: "8dp"
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
```

Thank you for any help :)

Edit:
I have found that I have been changing the wrong value and that the variable that needs changing has been marker with # NewHERE, however I am still unable to get it to work or get a variable from the py file into the kv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get a `Label` that expands vertically as it's text-content grows you can set its height to its texture height.

Also, to fit the text within available space (width) you can change `text_size`.

Thus you can modify the kvlang for `LabelColor` as,

```py
<LabelColor>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
    text_size: self.width, None
    size_hint_y: None
    height: self.texture_size[1]
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I added the self.texture_size[1] with huge excitement as I've been trying to get this to work for hours and unfortunately nothing changed.  The code is still as it was just with your addition.  I can still only change the height of all of the boxes together.  I do not want the size of the text itself to change.  Do you have any other suggestions, if so please lmk

Comment: Your suggestion did work, just needed to change height: to size: thank you very much for the suggestion as it lead to a few google searches that go me the full solution

Comment: This solution should fix the issue - *'clip-off text that doesn't fit within them'* . However, in any other cases, can you please elaborate what exactly you want.